# Android gradle sync Error Failed to resolve: com.flurry.android:analytics:10.0.1

Tags: android, flurry, flurry-analytics

I am trying to upgrade `flurry analytics(10.0.1)` library into our project. But `gradle sync` fails with the below error.

> Failed to resolve: com.flurry.android:analytics:10.0.1

How can I resolve this sync error??

Thanks.

Comment: paste your stacktrace

Comment: Error:(31, 20) Failed to resolve: com.flurry.android:analytics:10.0.1
Show in File Show in Project Structure dialog

Comment: Can u paste your codes in App/grade file

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android { compileSdkVersion 26
 buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 16
multiDexEnabled true} buildTypes {
  release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-project.txt' }}} dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    implementation 'com.flurry.android:analytics:10.0.1@aar' }

Comment: The error is simple you did not specify a location where you need to search for this particular dependency. You just need to add `jcenter()` in your repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flurry SDK is available via jcenter. You can add it to your application by including the following in your build.gradle file:

> Open your project/build.gradle file then add the `jcenter()` in your repository

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

> Once that is done add the dependency in your App/build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    ....
    implementation 'com.flurry.android:analytics:10.0.1@aar'
}
```

Comment: It was added before. allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}

Comment: And still you are getting the error ?? @keshavmurthy

Comment: Can you add your complete error trace and both build.gradle file content in question not on comment

Answer (score 0):

10.0.1 is not one of the available version numbers. The most recent Android version is 11.0.0, but 10.1.0 and 10.0.0 are also available. Update your implementation to one of those three version numbers, and it should work.